# Migrate content from one alfresco repository to other after up-gradation

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts, opencmis

We are upgrading from alfresco 5.0.1 to alfresco 5.2.2.

Actually it's not just upgradation, but it's a consolidation of 3 different projects.

Currently we have 3 projects in alfresco. 1st one is in alfresco 5.0.1, 2nd one is in alfresco 5.2 and 3rd one is in 5.0.

And here we have 3 separate repositories.

Now we are consolidating these 3 projects.

So we are going to keep only one repo. for all three projects and there will be 3 separate share for each application.

And in this case will keep one repository as is, but other 2 repositories we need to migrate.

So in above scenario after up-gradation we want to migrate actual repository contents from old alfresco repository to new alfresco repository with all associated metadata.

So please let me know if alfresco is having any in-build feature to achieve this requirements easily.

Also let me know, what are the other possible ways to achieve this.

All your inputs will be really appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Alfresco is keeping the data during migration. I don't really see your point : https://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/upgrade-process.html

Comment: You're not doing in place upgrade? If so, why?

Comment: @Lista I got your point, let me edit my question. So you will get exact Idea that what I want to say..

Comment: @Akah I have updated my question, I hope you got my requirements now. Please let me know if you need any other details. Thanks :)

Comment: Three separate Shares have different client side specifications? How are they going to know to query only "their part" of the repository?

Comment: @Lista we have different name space in content model for all three projects, so that part already completed. Now just the thing is to migrate content to final target repository..

Comment: Can someone please provide some inputs, what are the possible ways to do the repository migration?

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing out-of-the-box that will help you consolidate three separate repositories into a single repository.

Your best bet is likely to write an export script that will write the files out to the file system along with an XML file that describes the metadata. It will simplify things if you write the XML file in the same format that the Bulk File System Import Tool (BFSIT) expects when importing.

Write the data to a volume that can be mounted by the Alfresco server you are consolidating into.

Once the data is written and the volume is mounted, you can run a BFSIT import to bring the files and the metadata into the repository.

Using this approach you probably can avoid upgrading the 5.0.x servers.

This only addresses data. Of course you'll also need to deal with customizations you've made to the two 5.0.x servers. Hopefully, everything you've done in those other two servers are namespaced and isolated so that they won't collide with the third server. You'll need to test your 5.0.x customizations to make sure they will work with 5.2.x before cutting over.